# React Native Image not working Android both in emulator and in device

Tags: image, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

`<Image />` is shown in iOS simulator but not shown in Android emulator and device.

It's only not working when I use it as custom marker for google maps

```
<MapView.Marker
    coordinate={this.state.spot}
>
    <View style={styles.customMarker}>
        <Image style={styles.marker}
             source={images.customMarker}
             resizeMode='stretch'
        />
    </View>
</MapView.Marker>
```

Comment: What's `images.customMarker`

Comment: It's `require('../path/to/image.png)`

Answer (score 2):

it could be the problem with simulator as well as it happens with weak network
try completely resetting it. (as if it were a new iPhone). "Reset content and settings"
Keep  an eye on your image url as well.
Rebuild your project and run . It works for me.